# What kind of vulnerability result from known ssh-hostkey?

Tags: ssh, nmap, vulnerability

I saw there is [an NSE script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html) in `nmap` that can retrieve the `ssh-hostkey` (RSA or DSA) from the target host.

For example:

```
22/tcp open  ssh
|  ssh-hostkey: 2048 f0:58:ce:f4:aa:a4:59:1c:8e:dd:4d:07:44:c8:25:11 (RSA)
```

Can anyone explain what could happen if we can get `ssh-hostkey`? Is it a kind of misconfiguration of SSH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This script retrieves only the fingerprint of the public key (shown in your question) and on request the public key itself.

> Shows the target SSH server's key fingerprint and (with high enough verbosity level) the public key itself. It records the discovered host keys in nmap.registry for use by other scripts. Output can be controlled with the ssh_hostkey script argument.

[source nmap.org](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html)

As the public key by definition is public this serves only informational purposes on the client and poses no vulnerability/security threat at all.

The informational purposes I mentioned might be in the line of:

- prepopulating the list of known host keys for a SSH/SCP-Client
- checking if the host keys of servers have changed (to trigger an investigation about the reason, for instance)

The fingerprint of a public key serves to identify that key (make it easier to recognize) because it might be difficult to see when the complete key (2048 bit = 256 characters) has been altered. The fingerprint (normally called a *hash*) will be completely different even if only a single bit has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with obtaining host keys. If you offer SSH service and a client connects, then the host will tell it anyway. This is just informational. Occasionally one finds that some hosts share the same host key (nmap will tell you), which could be something to consider.